# In R, how to reverse a split()

Tags: r, split

In R, once the following code is ran:

```
temp <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

If I send only "temp" to someone else ...

What code can he use to put back slices of "temp" together?  He does not need to use "cyl" as column name; he can use whatever he wants.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

We can use `do.call` with `rbind`, but the order or rows may be different

```
do.call(rbind, temp)
```

---

If the column info is known, then `unsplit` can be useful as it will keep the same order as before the `split`

```
unsplit(temp, mtcars$cyl)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.  In do.call(rbind(), temp), can I add a column, so that the new table can differentiate the row is from list[[1]], list[[2]] and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` or `data.table`'s `rbindlist`. To identify which rows come from which element of the list we can use `.id`/`idcol` parameter.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(temp, .id = 'id')
data.table::rbindlist(temp, idcol = 'id')
```

By default it assigns name of the list as id column, if you want them as numbers you can remove the names from the list using `unname`.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(unname(temp), .id = 'id')
data.table::rbindlist(unname(temp), idcol = 'id')
```